# How to iterate two objects at a time by using thymeleaf?

Tags: thymeleaf

I am new to thymeleaf. I am trying to iterate two objects at a time on table. Because i am getting value from two objects.

I tried my way but it not working properly.

```
<tbody th:each="trn,iterStat : ${avngs}">
         <tr th:each="emp,iterStat : ${list}">
             <td th:text="${emp.name}">Name</td> 
             <td th:text="${emp.address}">VPA</td>
             <td th:text="${emp.accountno}">Accont No</td> 
             <td th:text="${trn.daylimit}">Yes</td>
             <td th:text="${trn.weeklimit}">Yes</td>
             <td th:text="${trn.monthlimit}">Yes</td>                 
         </tr>
</tbody>
```

Here, `emp.name,address,accountno` are getting correctly. But `trn.daylimit,weeklimit,monthlimit` are getting only same to remaining records

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: What is the result you trying to achieve? Do you want to have a e.g. category and subcategory?

Comment: @Aeseir: yes. In table last record subcategory values  are set to upper records.

Comment: Can you add some more information about your objects `${avngs}` and `${list}`. The way I understand is that you want to create multiple table bodies each having different list data. But you are using the same `${list}` for each table so you must be getting the tables with same list data.

Comment: @Ayush: i don't  want to create multiple table bodies, I don't know hoe to iterate tow objects at a time. so i wrote my own way.

Comment: still doesn't make sense. So you have two completely different Lists of objects with no relation between them and you want to iterate them at same time? How does this look is there a example website you can point to?

Comment: how does an `emp` relate to a `trn`?  Does a `trn` "have" or "contain" many `emp`s?

Answer (score 0):

Make some meaning out of this. I have two lists, part1 and part2, I get values of part 2 from the index of part 1. This considers that your part 1 and 2 are supposed to display values in a linear - side by side manner. I got my parts by splitting a string.

```
<tr th:each= "part1, status : ${part1}">
    <td th:text="${status.index + 1}"></td>
    <td th:text="${part1}"></td>
    <td th:text="${part2.get(status.index)}"></td>
</tr>
```